# CSS and JS files don't update in Phalcon app

Tags: phalcon

I have a Phalcon app where I added some HTML (in volt), JS and SCSS. I compiled my CSS into the `public` directory and my JS files are also there. Everything works. Then I try to change my JS or CSS, but Phalcon ignores all changes. If I delete the files and refresh the page, the page style is gone and when I put them back, the new files effectively show up.
It seems like Phalcon is saving a cached version of my assets, but where? And how do I clear this cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just solved this issue in vagrant by disabling send file support with **sendfile off;** parameter to nginx site.

Comment: Thanks. Just to add, this is a bug in VirtualBox and is also present in apache. http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html